# infinite events in computed vue property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have built a component that composed of an array(selectedItems) and a boolean (toggle).
the component has items array.

based on the current data both hold I created a computed property:

```
computed:{
   isValid(){
      const {toggle, selectedItems} = this
      return toggle && selectedItems.length || !toggle && selectedItems.length < items.length
   }
}
```

my model is an object that has all 3: `{selectedItems, isValid, toggle}`

I wrote a function to update the model (which is named `output`):

```
    updateModel(key, value) {
      this.$emit('update', { ...this.output, [key]: value })
    }
```

I'm calling this function when updating toggle or selectedItems, but I want it to be up to date with the validity property as well.

when I call that function in the computed it enters infinite loop of events for some reason, which I couldn't figure out.

Then I tried a different approach,
I created a watch on the computed `isValid` property and in the handler I call `updateModel` (the same way I tried to call it before, and that works.

Why calling it in the computed function causing it to some to be invoked again and again?

Thanks.

Comment: Dont do anything with side-effect in a computed. If you do and it affects the computed itself, you end up in an infinite loop like you just experienced.

Comment: why does it happen if I affect a field that has nothing to do with the computed property?

Comment: Can you provide the code for calling updateModel? And what is done with the event you emit?

Comment: I have defined `output` as the model of the component so on emit it supposed to update the model...   
what didn't work was the computed property above with calling to `updateModel` before returning
what works is to watch `isValid` value and call `updateModel` in the watch handler